# SetChecked() does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter

Hey guys on my Adapter ViewHolder.bind I have to check if some value is true, then check my checkbox. The problem is I cant use setCheck(tru) cause in kotlin doesnt apear.

Comment: You can still use `checkBox.setCheck(true)`, but Android Studio will suggest you to use property access syntax `checkBox.isChecked = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use following function to solve your problem

```
fun setChecked(viewId: Int, checked: Boolean) {
    (findView<View>(viewId) as Checkable).isChecked = checked
}
```

Comment: The views generally already have the `setChecked()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

To **check** the `Checkbox` use do this

```
 holder.checkBox!!.isChecked=true
```

And to **uncheck** `Checkbox` do this

```
  holder.checkBox!!.isChecked=false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lateinit var checkBox: CheckBox


checkBox = findViewById(R.id.notifcheckBox)
checkBox.isChecked = true
```